# The checkbox cannot return False when unchecked but can return True when checked

Tags: python, html, flask, web, phpmyadmin

**app.py**

```
@app.route('/register',methods=['GET','POST'])
def register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        details = request.form
        name = details['name']
        username = details['username']
        password = details['password']
        tel = details['tel']
        email = details['email']
        is_member = details['member']
        if is_member == 'on':
            is_member = True
        else:
            is_member = False
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
        query = '''INSERT INTO customers (name,username,password,tel,email,member) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)'''
        values = (name,username,password,tel,email,is_member)
        cursor.execute(query,values)
        mysql.connection.commit()
        cursor.close()
        return redirect(url_for('reg_success'))

    return render_template('reg_account.html')
```

**reg_account.html**

```
<script>
        $(doucment).ready(function(){
            $("#submit_detail").click(function(){
                $("#member").is(':checked',function(){
                    if ($(this).is(':checked')){
                        $(this).attr('value',"True");
                    } else{
                        $(this).attr('value',"False");
                    }
                    var is_member = $("#member").val();   
                }) 
            })
        })
    </script>
{% block content %} 
<form method="POST" class="login_details">
        <h3>Registration</h3>
        <!-- <legend>Log-in Details</legend> -->
        <p><label for="name">Name:</label><input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="35" required></p>
        <p><label for="tel">Mobile:</label><input type="text" name="tel" id="tel" size="35" required></p>
        <p><label for="email">Email:</label><input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="35"></p>
        <p><label for="username">Username:</label><input type="text" name="username" id="username" size="35" required></p>
        <p><label for="password">Password:</label><input type="text" name="password" id="password" size="35" required></p>
        <p><label for="cpw">Confirm password:</label><input type="text" name="cpw" id="cpw" size="35" required></p>
        <p><label for="member">Apply as member?</label><input type="checkbox" name="member" id="member"></p>
        <p><input type="submit" id="submit_detail" value="Register"></p>
    
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Error:

```
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'member'
```

I would like to make the result of `is_member` returns False when the checkbox in `#member` is unchecked but however I do not understand why it works when I ticked the checkbox then the result could be stored into database? I tried to debug a few times but still could not find a possible solution so could anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check

```
if 'member' in data:
# your code
else:
#your code
```

Instead of

```
is_member = data['member']
```

Problem here is you are not sending member from UI if it unchecked. Hence flask is not able to find it in data dict.

Comment: Is it ```details``` instead of ```data``` because I used ```details = request.form```?

Comment: Yeah. Sorry my bad